# Android videoView overlapping issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, video, android-viewpager, android-videoview

I have used VideoView in view pager with horizontal scrolling. The issue is if i swipe from one page to another the second page shows the played image thumbnail of previous video.

In the following image, the front crop is the thumbnail of previous video and the background is actual video of current page.[image: The dark background is actual video of current page, and the foreground thumbnail is of previous video]

I am just doing this when the page changes

```
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Video")) {
       ImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       VideoFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       youTubeViewLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

       VideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url.replaceAll(" ", "%20")));
       VideoView.seekTo(5000);
       VideoView.requestFocus();
    }
```

Comment: Always post some code with the question, If you are given the same question without the code, would you be able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that the VideoView is catching the swiping event
To solve this:
you just need to stop VideoView from consuming your onTouch event, try making a custom VideoView class, and override onTouch method, by returning always false(**returning true on boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev**)).